# How to use PDO::lastInsertId()?

Tags: php, pdo

```
$sql='INSERT INTO complaints(complaint_id) values(default)';
$db->query($sql,array());

//get newly added complaint_id

$complaint_id=$db->lastInsertId();
```

I used above code to get last insert ID from complaints table. But it gives an error like 
`Fatal error: Call to undefined method EMMACore\Utils\DBConnection::lastInsertId() in /h...` Can anybody tell me what is wrong in my application.Thanks.

Comment: `$db` is not a PDO instance, it is `EMMACore\Utils\DBConnection` instance

Comment: Can you show some more code? This problem usually appears when you run the method from the statement class instead of the pdo class itself. But to be honest, your code looks fine, assuming that db is the PDO class.

Comment: @ zerkms : `$db` is database connection. it is PDO instance.

Comment: @Mangala Edirisinghe: php isn't agree with your opinion. show us `var_dump($db instanceof PDO);`

Comment: show more relevant codes especially your database connection

Comment: @zerkms :var_dump($db)- `object(EMMACore\Utils\DBConnection)#26 (8) {
  ["db":"EMMACore\Utils\DBConnection":private]=>
  object(PDO)#27 (0) {
  }
  ["dbhost":"EMMACore\Utils\DBConnection":private]=>
  string(9) "localhost"
  ["dbname":"EMMACore\Utils\DBConnection":private]=>
  string(8) "emmacore"
  ["dbuser":"EMMACore\Utils\DBConnection":private]=>
  string(4) "root"
  ["dbpwd":"EMMACore\Utils\DBConnection":private]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["query_counter":"EMMACore\Utils\DBConnection":private]=>
  int(2)
  ["total_time_expended":"EMMACore\Utils\DBConnection":private]=>
 ......

Comment: @Mangala Edirisinghe: not `var_dump($db);` but `var_dump($db instanceof PDO);`. Well, we see enough - it **IS NOT** a PDO instance. PDO instance is stored in its `db` property. Look through that library documentation to get how to call PDO's `lastInsertId()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most case, the PDO instance is a property of `EMMACore\Utils\DBConnection`, so check the source code and find it out.

Something like: `$db->getDbh()->lastInsertId();` where `getDbh` (or something like that) returns the PDO instance.

***Edit:*** After seeing your result of `var_dump()`, that is for sure.

Comment: "In most case"?. After OP has given `var_dump()` we know that *for sure*

Comment: @zerkms That's just a guess :), I answered before the OP show the result of `var_dump()`.

Comment: Not a guess anymore http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809752/how-to-use-pdolastinsertid#comment14067151_10809752 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`class db extends PDO`

you can refer to this link [PHP PDO Wrapper Class](http://code.google.com/p/php-pdo-wrapper-class/) for example.